# Video compression is much higher and lower quality than expected when using the following FFmpeg commands

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I want to compress video with high quality using FFmpeg but the files become much smaller than expected and quality is lost as a result. How I can a reach expected quality and filesize instead of the output I am now getting.

The quality of video coming is not as expected. FFmpeg is converting the original video which is 11.3GB in size to 797 MB only.

Codec details of video is available here:

> [image]

I wanted to convert video in **MP4 - Codec: H264 with high quality**.

11.3GB should be compressed to **4GB**. Expected media information can be seen at:

> [image]

And medium size should be compressed to **1.25GB**. Expected media information can be seen at:

> [image]

I ran below commands which produces me the output as follows:

File sizes can be seen here:

> [image]

```
ffmpeg -i Orignal-Video.mov -s 720x576 -b 512k -vcodec mpeg1video -acodec copy Compressed-Video_Output_1.mov
```

**Produces video of 787 MB**

```
ffmpeg -i Orignal-Video.mov -c:v libx264 -crf 24 -b:v 1M -c:a aac Compressed-Video-Output_2.mp4
```

**Produces video of 413 MB**

```
ffmpeg -i Orignal-Video.mov -map_metadata -1 -c:v libx265 -crf 20 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -vol 512 -tag:v hvc1 -sn Compressed-Video-Output_3.mp4
```

**Produces video of 797 MB**

What can be done to have better quality while achieving a smaller file size?

Comment: I'm confused. Your title talks about quality but you're only looking at the file size. Did you actually look inside? Is the quality *really* insufficient? 800 MB for 50 minutes of DVD-resolution video sounds very reasonable.

Comment: The quality of video is bit pixlet in comparison to orignal. We need video in high DVD quality only. Thinking the quality gone down because the file size becomes very less. Our expectation of video is like I have shared in question. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Choose 1: Specific quality *or* specific file size

- You can either choose a quality level, or choose what file size you want.
- Most users want a specific quality, and file size is less important.
- Choosing a specific file size is only recommended if you have limited space, such as a small USB drive.

### Specific quality

With libx264 (H.264) and libx265 (H.265/HEVC), if you want all of your videos to have the same level of quality, you basically only need to:

1. Use the highest `-crf` value that provides an acceptable quality.
2. Use the slowest `-preset` that you have patience for.
3. Encode your batch of videos with the same `-crf` and `-preset`.

This will allow the encoder to be efficient and apply the appropriate amount of bits to achieve the desired quality level. Output file size is not predictable.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) and [FFmpeg Wiki: H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) for more details.

### Specific file size

If you need a specific file size use two-pass encoding as shown in both links above. However, there is no reason to do this unless you need the video to be a specific size.

#### Don't use bitrate as a quality metric

> FFmpeg is converting the original video which is 11.3GB in size to 797 MB only.

The original is DV, an ancient format made for old video cameras and editing. It was never an efficient, highly compressed format. That's not what it was designed for. The output is HEVC, a much newer format, and is encoded by a capable, efficient encoder. Comparing their bitrates is meaningless.

Ignore the bitrate. Watch the video. If it looks much worse than the original then decrease the `-crf` until it is acceptable.

Comment: Also, perhaps encode only one or two minutes to iterate faster.

Comment: This was fantastic explanation. Many Many Thanks for your help. Salute to you. @Daniel, sorry, I did not get you that how can I encode for one or two minutes to iterate faster, when my video is of 1 hrs.